# Why my page doesn't load after adding this infinite loop to my javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I have created this infinite loop in javascript, in order to run a setTimeout function. The problem is that, by doing this, my page doesn't even load in the first place.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function blurDiv() {
    console.log("here");
    rankingList.style.filter="blur(0.7)";
} 

function loadContent() {
    console.log("loaded");
    $( "#ranking-container" ).load("index.php #ranking-list");
    rankingList.style.filter="blur(0)";  
}

while(true) {
    setTimeout(blurDiv, 4000);

    setTimeout(loadContent, 5000); 
}
```

I was expecting that the loop would only run another iteration after those 5 seconds.

Comment: Use `setInterval(...)` instead of `while(true){setTimeout(...)`

Comment: why the comment tho? make that an answer and get that yummy rep @HarunYilmaz

Comment: @Gibor can't miss the opportunity :D thanks

Comment: Pro Tipp: What you are doing is done with websockets instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` instead of `while(true){setTimeout()}`

```js
function blurDiv() {
    console.log("here");
    // Other stuff here
} 

function loadContent() {
    console.log("loaded");
    // Other stuff here
}


setInterval(blurDiv, 5000);
setInterval(loadContent, 5000);
```

Explanation:

`setTimeout()` is an async function which means JS does not wait for it to complete and continues to run. Therefore, with the loop `while(true)`, it creates two timeout callbacks in every turn which will result in a huge amount (a really huge amount) of timeout callbacks and **will never get out of that `while(true)` loop**.

However, by using `setInterval()` you create a timer that will fire the callback in every cycle (interval).

Answer (score 2):

Harun's answer is sufficient to solve your issue. Additionally, if you want to know more about why you were getting that behaviour, it is due to something called the `Event Loop`.

Check out this awesome [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&vl=iw) by Jake Archibald.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval (see other answer) or a callback

```
function loadIt()
   $("#ranking-container").load("index.php #ranking-list",function() {
     rankingList.style.filter="blur(0.7)";
     setTimeout(loadIt,4000)
   });
   rankingList.style.filter="blur(0)";  
 }
 loadIt();
```